# Integration problem of a modified 'standard integral'

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

Consider $\int\limits_0^\infty ye^{-y}e^{-xy}dy$ I can use the fact that $\int\limits_0^\infty u^ne^{-u}=n!$

Clearly, $\int\limits_0^\infty ye^{-y}e^{-xy}dy=\int\limits_0^\infty ye^{-y(1+x)}dy$. Hence, for $\int\limits_0^\infty ye^{-y}dy=1!=1$. However I don't understand how to apply that modification in the integral (apart from the fact that the answer is $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$). Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Substitute $u = (1+x)y$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, so let $u=(1+x)y$, then $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x}ue^{-u} du = \frac{1}{1+x}\int\limits_0^\infty ue^{-u} du = \frac{1}{1+x}\cdot 1!$, so I suppose I made a mistake somewhere.. Could you tell me where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $$\int\limits_0^\infty ye^{-y}e^{-xy}dy$$
Use the substitution $u = y(1+x)$ so $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}y} = 1 + x$ and hence $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}u} = \dfrac{1}{1+x}$.

Our integral can be written as $$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{u}{1+x}e^{-u}\, \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}u} \mathrm{d}u = \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{u}{1+x}e^{-u} \times \frac{1}{1+x} \, \mathrm{d}u$$
So we get $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\int\limits_0^\infty ue^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$ Tada.